# LAB: Login name. Error with printing an entire string if it’s over a certain number of characters

Tags: java

I'm working on this lab:

Write a program that creates a login name for a user, given the user's first name, last name, and a four-digit integer as input. Output the login name, which is made up of the first five letters of the last name, followed by the first letter of the first name, and then the last two digits of the number (use the % operator). If the last name has less than five letters, then use all letters of the last name.

I have a code that works for input where the last name is five letters or more, but am confused on how to add the part where there is a last name with less than five letters. Do I use an if statement?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LabProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       
      String userFirstName;
        String userLastName;
        int birthYear;
        String loginName;
        
        userFirstName = scnr.next();
        userLastName = scnr.next();
        birthYear = scnr.nextInt();
        
        loginName = userLastName.substring(0,4); 
        loginName = loginName + userFirstName.charAt(0);
        loginName = loginName + (birthYear % 100) ;
        
        System.out.println("Your login name: " + loginName);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do I use an if statement?" Yes.

Comment: JavaScript and Java are entirely different languages, please only tag with the language you're actually using. Also, please edit the title of your question to provide a title that actually summarizes your question. The title _"LAB: Login name"_  is not helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the title and extra tags at first. I just started on this website and just started coding ! Thanks for any input :)

Answer (score 1):

`Do I use an if statement?`
Yes

Over here:

```
        loginName = userLastName.substring(0,4); 
        loginName = loginName + userFirstName.charAt(0);
        loginName = loginName + (birthYear % 100) ;
```

You can simply add

```
        if (userLastName.length()<5)
            loginName = userLastName;
            //this will initialize loginName with all the characters available

        else 
            loginName = userLastName.substring(0,4);
            /* 
               in my opinion this will return only 4 characters and not the fifth one
               If that's the case, make the .substring(0,5);
            */

        loginName = loginName + userFirstName.charAt(0);
        loginName = loginName + (birthYear % 100) ;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).